# How to make MSBuild print output from a custom tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have a project, which use a .rules file to build some non-c++ sources. How to make MSBuild print diagnostic output from this tool? -- Precisely cerr stream.

(I silently presume, the M$ team have not reached that level of insanity, to give the custom building tools functionality without possibility to print errors from them.)

Comment: Have you tried to increase verbosity level? Or try format messages according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26%28v=vs.100%29.aspx? Do you build non c++ sources in c++ project?

Comment: @PaloMisik, verbosity=diagnostic. The tool is not written by me, so I would investigate the code, rewrite it, and still I would have a problem as, I would need to correct each new version I would download. Yes, I do build non-c++ sources in a c++ project. The library's sources I am trying to build are done that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually noticed you marked question with label visual-studio-2008. I guess it means your custom build tool processes non cpp files in vc2008 project? If so, I think it is not built by msbuild but with vcbuild.

In this case try to add **echo on** in front of command executed by custom tool.
Vcbuild creates batch files in %temp% that first line contains @echo off and then it is executed. So if you add echo on  you should see complete output in output window including command line used for command execution.